# ServiceStack DTO with inheritance

Tags: servicestack

According to Mythz ([Getting ServiceStack to retain type information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750571/getting-servicestack-to-retain-type-information/10759250#10759250)) he recommends not using inheritance in DTOs. What about the use case where I want every request to optionally provide an API key, or a location parameter? Are interfaces bad to use but abstract classes are ok? Anyone have any recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case, "every request to optionally provide an API key, or a location parameter" is traditionally handled in SS through [filter attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes)

[Here's an example where a required authorization header is managed both server-side and client-side.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386092/149060)

Given the right requirements, Mythz has recommended the use of a custom interface in DTOs:  "Request DTO that implements a custom ITenant interface that just has a Tenant property. Another solution is to use a IHttpRequest.Tennant() extension method that you can re-use inside all services which inspects the AbsoluteUri or RawUrl properties." See this comment: ([Multi-tenant ServiceStack API, same deployment to respond to requests on different hostnames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206488/multi-tenant-servicestack-api-same-deployment-to-respond-to-requests-on-differe#comment27368612_18206488))

Comment: How bad would it be if I just added another interface (in addition to the IReturn<T>) to my DTOs? By "bad", I mean will it harm efficiency of serialization?

Comment: I couldn't say.  I think this is just something you have to test.

Answer (score 2):

I use interfaces and then check for implementations of the interface in a request filter.